# Changing multiple objects using Ramda lens

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming, ramda.js

I currently have a data structure that looks mostly like that following:

```
var data = { "id": 123,
    "modules": [{
        "id": 1,
        "results": [{
            "status": "fail",
            "issues": [
                {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
                {"type": "remove", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
                {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}}
            ]
        }]
    },{
        "id": 2
        "results": [{
            "status": "pass",
            "issues": [
                {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
                {"type": "remove", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
                {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}}
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have been trying to use Ramda to make a compose query that could do something like, change the status of all issues that are of a certain type.

I have been trying to do something along the lines of composing the lens's through R.map/R.chain but I can't seem to work it out. Something like this is what im trying to do:

```
let approvedData = R.compose(
  R.set(R.__, 'approve', Data)
  R.lensProp('status')
  R.map(R.lensIndex),
  R.lensProp('issues'),
  R.map(R.lensIndex),
  R.lensProp('results'),
  R.map(R.lensIndex),
  R.lensProp('modules')
)(Data)
```

And have it return back the full data set with the statuses changed.

**UPDATE:**

I have come up with some code that will do what I'm trying to do, but I'm still struggling to make each of the steps into functions that can then be composed:

```
R.over(R.lensProp('modules'), R.map(
  R.over(R.lensProp('results'), R.map(
    R.over(R.lensProp('issues'), R.map(
      R.set(R.lensProp('status'), 'approve')
    ))
  ))
), Data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your updated solution looks fine to me, but it is possible to create the transformation function via composition:

```
//  update$modules$results$issues$status :: (String -> String) -> Object -> Object
var update$modules$results$issues$status = R.compose(
  R.over(R.lensProp('modules')),
  R.map,
  R.over(R.lensProp('results')),
  R.map,
  R.over(R.lensProp('issues')),
  R.map,
  R.over(R.lensProp('status'))
);

update$modules$results$issues$status(R.always('approve'))(data);
```

Comment: Why the $ (dollar sign) on update$modules$results$issues$status? Is it something related to FP? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're probably having doubts around the transformation of values within arrays.

Now, with the data being

```
const data = {
  "id": 123,
  "modules": [{
    "id": 1,
    "results": [{
      "status": "fail",
      "issues": [
        {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
        {"type": "remove", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
        {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}}
      ]
    }]
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "results": [{
      "status": "pass",
      "issues": [
        {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
        {"type": "remove", "status": "warn", "data": {}},
        {"type": "change", "status": "warn", "data": {}}
      ]
    }]
  }]
};
```

What you want to do is create lenses for each of the keys that contain arrays. In your specific case they are `modules`, `results` and `issues`.

On top of that, you'll need a lens to the key you want to modify, which is `status`.

So:

```
const modulesLens = lensProp('modules')
const resultsLens = lensProp('results')
const issuesLens = lensProp('issues')
const statusLens = lensProp('status')
```

Now, with these in place, all you have to do is put them together. (I've broken them down to facilitate the comprehension)

```
const approveIssues = over(
  modulesLens,
  map(over(
    resultsLens,
    map(over(
      issuesLens,
      map(set(statusLens, 'approve'))
    ))
  ))
)
```

Now all that's left to do is feed `approvedIssues` with the data you'd like to transform, which is our `data`.

So, finally.

```
//Running this
const approvedData = approveIssues(data)

/* Outputs this
{
  "id": 123,
  "modules": [{
    "id": 1,
    "results": [{
      "issues": [
        {"data": {}, "status": "approve", "type": "change"},
        {"data": {}, "status": "approve", "type": "remove"},
        {"data": {}, "status": "approve", "type": "change"}
      ],
      "status": "fail"
    }]}, {
      "id": 2,
      "results": [{
        "issues": [
          {"data": {}, "status": "approve", "type": "change"},
          {"data": {}, "status": "approve", "type": "remove"},
          {"data": {}, "status": "approve", "type": "change"}],
        "status": "pass"
    }]}
  ]}
*/
```

In that case I didn't necessarily have to use `compose`, but that would be possible as well I guess.